# Is this elementary proof of fundamental theorem of algebra correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-functions

There is an elementary proof which considers the polynomial $ p(z) $, $z \in \mathbb{C}$ as a function of $ (r,\theta) $ where $ z= r e^{-i \theta} $, $r\ge 0$ . There are two assumptions-

**Assumption 1**:  $z^{n}=a $, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$   has a solution for all integer $n$. This can be shown to be true for some $z\in \mathbb{C} $ using the field structure of $\mathbb{C} $.

**Assumption 2**: Consider points A,B,C,D on a circle. C and D lie on the two different arcs with endpoints A and B. If theres are two connected curves lying inside the circle, one connecting A and C, another connecting B and D, then the curves must intersect somewhere inside the circle. The proof of this is quite involved are requires something called Jordan curve theorem.

The only elementary theory used are as follows:

1. Properties of continuous functions on two dimensional plane. One important point is that continuous functions with real values divide the plane into two regions, positive and negative. The zeros separating these regions form a connected curve or region.
2. Real and complex part of a continuous complex function are continuous.
3. The value of a polynomial $p(x) , x \in \mathbb{R}$ with real coefficients is dominated by its higher power for large absolute values of $x$.
4. $\operatorname{Re}(z) < |z|,  \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.

The idea is to track the real and imaginary parts of a polynomial $p(r,\theta)$ separately. First showing that the real part $ \operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))$ has at least one zero on a big circle $r=R$ on the complex plane, we can further show that the curve containing this zero is open. Further analysis shows that the values of imaginary part of $p(r,\theta), \operatorname{Im}(p(r,\theta))$ is positive on some point of this curve and negative at another for large $r$. Then $\operatorname{Im}(p(r,\theta))=0$ somewhere on the particular curve $\operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0$ we were tracking. This gives a solution for $p(r,\theta)=0$.

The proof can be visualized in the following way-

Writing $ z= r e^{-i \theta} $ we can find a big enough $r=R$ such that $ \operatorname{Re}(p(R,\theta)) $ is positive at $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n} $ and negative at $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\pi} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n} $. This is because  $\operatorname{Re}(p(R,\theta)) $ is dominated by $r^{n}\cos(n\theta + \phi)$. $\phi$ is the angle of the complex coefficient of $z^{n}$. So $\operatorname{Re}(p(R,\theta))=0$ at some point in the interval $\theta= \left( \frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n} , \frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\pi} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n} \right) \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $ \operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0 $ is nonempty. As a consequence of this and the continuity of $ \operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta)) $, $ \operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0 $ containing this point forms a connected curve on the complex plane.

The arc $r=R$ between $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n}$ and $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\pi} {n}  + \frac {\phi} {n} $ is called a even sector for even $k$ and is called a odd sector for odd $k$. On these sectors, the leading coefficient of $\operatorname{Im}(p(r,\theta))$ tends towards $\infty$ in the even sectors and towards $-\infty$ in the odd sectors. So if any of the connected curves $\operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0$ cross the arc $r=R$ in an even sector and an odd sector, we must have a root on this curve.

If we increase $r \ge R$ continuously on any sector, we get a zero for $\operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0$ for some $\theta$. Continuity of $p(r,\theta)$ implies that we get a connected curve for $ \operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0 $ in any sector for $r\ge R$.  Now, zeros of a continuous function divide the plane into two disconnected parts. One of the parts is finite in area if the curve is closed. Otherwise both areas are unbounded. Here, since $\operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta) \ne 0$ $ \forall r \ge R$ and $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n} $ or $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\pi} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n} $, $\operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0$ cannot be closed.

Now, there is some curve $\operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0$ which crosses the arc $r=R$ odd number of times on any sector. If we start from an even sector, it must cross $r=R$ on another sector which is odd. This can be demonstrated using  exhaustion since there are only finite numbers of arcs (a sequence of $2m$ consecutive integers cannot be paired in only disjoint or nested (even,even) and (odd,odd) pairs). Let us call this curve $f(r,\theta)$.

$\operatorname{Im}(p(R,\theta)) $ is dominated by $r^{n}\sin(n\theta + \phi)$. So, on $f(r,\theta)$,  $\operatorname{Im}(p(r,\theta)) $ is positive somewhere in the even sector and negative somewhere in the odd sector for big enough $r$ , say $r=K$. There are two arcs on the circle $r=K$. On any one of these arcs, $\operatorname{Im}(p(K,\theta))=0 $. for some $\theta$. However, if we consider only one arc, $\operatorname{Im}(p(K,\theta))=0 $ can hold only for odd number of points. So the connected curve $\operatorname{Im}(p(K,\theta))=0 $ must intersect the other arc. So on $r=K$, we have $\operatorname{Re}(p(K,\theta))=0 $ at two points (at least) and $\operatorname{Im}(p(K,\theta))=0 $ at two other $\theta$ between the previous two. This implied that the curves intersect somewhere inside the circle $r=K$.  This gives a solution for $p(r,\theta)=0$.

Additionally, $f(r,\theta)$ is not asymptotic to $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n}$ or $\theta=\frac {2\pi k} {n} + \frac {\pi} {n} + \frac {\phi} {n}$. This can be proven by using the fact that $\operatorname{Re}(z) < |z|,  \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. If this was not true, domination of $\operatorname{Im}(p(r,\theta))$ on $f(r,\theta)$ by $r^{n}$ would be problematic since $\sin(n \theta + \phi)$ might tend towards zero for increasing $r$.

Finally, for every root found, we can do division algorithm to get another polynomial of degree $n-1$. We know that quartic and lower order polynomials with complex roots are always solvable using radicals. So induction shows that all polynomials with real coefficients are solvable on the complex plane.

Comment: I said $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, not for any particular value.

Comment: Uh, it wouldn't, clearly.  Sorry.

Comment: Can you explain or is it your feeling? There is a theorem called [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) which says that the two questions are equivalent. However, although both my proof and this theorem generate the same maximum radius in which all the roots lie, the proof of this theorem requires much deeper theory than what I sued.

Comment: In my mind I had substituted "an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$" for where you had written "$z^n$".  My mistake, apologies.

Comment: Can you clarify  "$ \operatorname{Re}(p(r,\theta))=0 $ containing this point forms a continuous curve on the complex plane", please. Why should the zero-set be connected?

Comment: $Re(p(r,\theta))$ is a continuous function on the $(r,\theta)$ plane. So the positive and negative regions for this function on the plane are separated by continuous curves. There can be multiple such curves. I only show there is one on which $Im(p(r,\theta))=0$ is satisfied at some point.

Comment: So you aren't claiming it is connected. However, why are its connected components continuous curves? Why can't it be something like $xy$ whose zero-set is the union of the two coordinate axes?

Comment: For $xy=0$, either $x=0$, $y=0$ or both. All of these curves are continuous.

Comment: But the union of the two curves is not itslef a curve, your property 4 is true of the union, but not for the reasons you give. You need to talk about connectedness rather than the IVT, I expect.

Comment: Rob Arthan I think you are right. I updated my answer. However, if I consider connected curves, I need to use Jordan curve theorem  . Then the proof is no more elementary and is equally hard as using the theory of holomorphic functions, if not more.

Comment: If you like elementary proofs of the FTA, [check this](https://www.ime.usp.br/~oliveira/FTAAUTHOR.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Ivo Terek. Incidentally I read this proof today morning.

Comment: I stopped reading after seeing 2 things I don't get : In your list of 4 elementary properties, I cannot understand what #1 is saying. In the 2nd sentence following this list ,you have "the curve containing this zero is open" What curve? And what is an open curve?

Comment: @user254665 The curve is $Re(p(r,\theta))=0$ which passes through the particular $Re(p(R,\theta_{0})=0)$ . Open curves are complement of closed curves (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedCurve.html) in the family of connected curves. Here I am emphasizing that the open curve also divides the complex plane into at least  two parts, one with $Re(p(r,\theta))>0$ and another with $Re(p(r,\theta))<0$.There can be more curves like this, there can be loops in the curve and much more, but **at least** two divisions are created by the curve $Re(p(r,\theta))=0$

Answer (score 1):

Conclusion: My proof is correct. This is because the first proof by Gauss followed the same procedure I used and assumed Jordan curve theorem to be true. Here is a [link](http://math.huji.ac.il/~ehud/MH/Gauss-HarelCain.pdf)

I just reinvented the wheel